# Impersonation in windows application (c#.NET)

Tags: .net, impersonation, windows

Can we do impersonation for connecting to remote machine using LOGONUSER function from windows 7 to windows server 2000 NT in windows application?

If we can, than could please provide me hint or sample code.........!

Comment: How are you wanting to connect to a remote machine? What are you wanting to accomplish?

Comment: my application connects to IBM MQ manager(on server: windows 2000 NT) and puts the message on the queue.I am able to connect to MQ manager but when i try to put message on the queue i getting authorization error. So,I am trying to use IMPERSONATION to put message on the queue .....will this be possible to do?

Comment: Does the user-id attempting to do this actually have access to the MQ? Looking online suggests to me that it uses impersonation by default.

Comment: Yes.The user-id and password admin's, where IBM MQ is running on the server.